# Error in opening and writing to a file

Tags: file, go, io

I want to open a file and write some text to it, however I get the following error:

```
.\hello.go:13: cannot use msg (type string) as type []byte in argument to f.Write
```

Here's my code so far:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
)

func printer(msg string) (err error) {
    f, err := os.Create("helloworld.txt")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    f.Write(msg)
    return err
}

func main() {
    printer("Hello World")
}
```

Comment: Your post lacks a question. Even if it seems clear, always specify your question.

Comment: I think you are being pedantic. The question was very clear.

Comment: No, it's not. I can imagine multiple serious questions for your description, many more with some malintent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `io.WriteString(f, msg)`, `f.Write([]byte(msg))` or `io.Copy(f, strings.NewReader(msg))`.